# Edit Instagram Dev-Account Information

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

today I registered my Instagram-Account as Developer Account. There was an form, asking for a website, phone-number and description

[image: register-form]

Unfortunately I entered the wrong url at the field "Your website". But I can`t find, where I can change it to the right one?

Do you know, where I can change this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you find what you are looking for here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

Comment: This is the page where i can edit all my apps. That's not what I was looking for. I want to edit my developer Account Informations, entered in the Screenshot in my question above.

Comment: I am looking for same answer:/